# How to generate multiple barcode image to a printable area in a page PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, barcode

I am working on a small inventory manager web application using PHP,jquery,mysql.... I want to add a barcode functionality to the app

Please I got this code to use on here after several searches; thumb-up to the poster.
But I am stuck here:

I wan to generate multiple of the barcode image to a printable area by selecting item/items with productcode/productid from the datatable on the same page and use the add button to add it to the printable area one after the other?

```
   <style> 
   @font-face { 
  font-family: barcode; 
  src: url(free3of9.ttf); 
   }
    </style>

    <body> ABC 
    <div style='font-family:barcode;font-size:32px;'> 
   123456789    </div> DEF</body>

      </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So this works for 1, How do you want to present many? Can you provide more code in regards to what you have tried or maybe an example of what you would like to see?

Comment: unfortunately, this wont work either. i got the code in a post in stackoverflow here. it look much of some sort of code that works but for some reason i would know......i couldn't get it to work. The problem i have is simple: I want to generate barcode from a select/input value; i am looking into using a barcode font as i deemed it could be easier for me to use to generate multiple barcode; i will post the one that works but could only generate a single output.....Thanks for attendance, however, i really need solution to this my little-but-time-consuming problem.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this @BabatundeMisbah - did you look at http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make use of this font, you need to have uploaded it to your web server along with the page you are using. This exmaple will do what you have described with JQuery, yet the Barcode will not be style since jsfiddle does not host the Font.

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/72ewdoj4/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="form">
    <li>
        <label>Top Text:</label>
        <input type="text" id="top" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Barcode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bar" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Bottom Text:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bottom" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <button id="add">Add</button>
</ul>
<hr />
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <td> <span class="label">ABC</span>
 <span class="bar label">123456789</span>
 <span class="label">DEF</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: barcode;
    src: url(3OF9_NEW.TTF);
}
.label {
    display: block;
}
.bar {
    font-family:barcode;
    font-size:32px;
}
#results {
    width: 100%;
}
#results td {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.form li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.form li label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var newLabel = "<tr><td>"
        newLabel += "<span class='label'>" + $("#top").val() + "</span>";
        newLabel += "<span class='bar label'>" + $("#bar").val() + "</span>";
        newLabel += "<span class='label'>" + $("#bottom").val() + "</span>";
        newLabel += "</td></td>";
        $("#results").append(newLabel);
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice demonstration :)

Comment: @twisty you are a life saver! This almost got me mad......the exact solution have been looking all the heck for......I couldn't thank you so enough. Thank you very much. It works perfectly.

Comment: @twisty can you help with the code to clear all the generated "results" at once e.g.clear function in a button something like that. say after printing the full list generated, then clear and start generating some other ones. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Easy, just set the HTML to null. Like so: `$("#clear").click(function(){ $("#results").html(""); });`